# How can I get Twitter favorites using the get_liked_tweets function between two dates with the library academictwitter?

Tags: r, twitter

Using R, I know how to get tweets between two dates with the package academictwitter, but the
"start_tweets" and "end_tweets" expressions do not seem to work in the "get_liked_tweets"function. Is there a way to get liked tweets of a user between two dates using this R package?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, there are no dates assigned to linked Tweets.